# Can't print Chinese if using Go to exec python scripts

Tags: python, go

I use below command to run python 3.7.4 file via Go.

```
Go exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "path_to_python_exe", "python_script_file")
```

Below script will print "abc" without the Chinese:

```
print ("abc")
print ("系统")
```

and it print nothing and return no error:

```
print ("系统")
print ("abc")
```

When I run "python test.py" in windows/linux terminal, it works well.

I get the output with go as below:

```
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
cmd.Start()

reader := bufio.NewReader(stdout)
output := make([]string, 0)
for {
    line, err2 := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err2 != nil || io.EOF == err2 {
        break
    }
    output = append(output, line)
}

cmd.Wait()

return strings.Join(output, "")
```

Comment: For encoding do you use UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Comment: Are you trying to print Chinese in a cmd prompt window?

Comment: How do you print the output? `exec.Command` does not directly redirect the command's output. Can you print chinese with pure go by using `fmt`? Can you check the output obtained by Go from python command if it contains correct output (or at least length of it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below codes, it works well:

```
   import sys,io,platform
   if(platform.system()=='Windows'):
      import sys,io
      sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to print Chinese, you have to create a cmd prompt that can display Chinese.  Start regedit and navigate to

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont
```

Add a new string

```
Name: 935
Value: *新宋体
```

This will appear as NSimSun.  This is on Win7.  I haven't tried it on W10 yet - it may accept NSimSun instead of the Chinese equivalent.  I can't remember how I got the equivalent Chinese name.

Close regedit, start a new cmd prompt.  Pop up the properties, select the font and change it to NSimSun.

Now run you little piece of code that prints English and Chinese and you should see the Chinese as well as the English bits.

As for the GoLang bits, you will have to look at @TehSphinX's answer.

Comment: One upvote from me for the cmd/windows specific parts.

Answer (score 0):

In Go `exec.Command` is not executing anything, yet. It returns a `exec.Cmd` struct which you have to execute e.g. with the `Run` method it provides.

The output of the command you execute is then piped back to Go and not to the console directly.

A working example using the `Output` function to execute and capture the output:

```golang
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "test.py")
    bts, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(bts))
}
```

`test.py` file:

```py
# coding=UTF-8

print("hello")
print("系统")
```